# Adding additional objects to an array on conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to sort the following array of objects:

```js
var input = [
          { name: 'Trevor Hansen', group: 'Group 1' },
          { name: 'Britta Holt', group: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'Jane Smith ', group: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'Sandra Adams', group: 'Group 1' },
          { name: 'Ali Connors', group: 'Group 1' },
          { name: 'John Smith', group: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'Sandra Williams', group: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'Tucker Smith', group: 'Group 1' },
        ],
```

This should be the result:

```js
var result = [
          { header: 'Group 1' },
          { name: 'Sandra Adams', group: 'Group 1' },
          { name: 'Ali Connors', group: 'Group 1' },
          { name: 'Trevor Hansen', group: 'Group 1' },
          { name: 'Tucker Smith', group: 'Group 1' },
          { divider: true },
          { header: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'Britta Holt', group: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'Jane Smith ', group: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'John Smith', group: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'Sandra Williams', group: 'Group 2' },
        ],
```

After sorting the array, a header object needs to be added before each group followed by a divider object between groups but before a new header.

This is my current code, to sort the array:

```js
function compare(a, b) {
        const valueA = a.group.toUpperCase();
        const valueB = b.group.toUpperCase();

        let comparison = 0;
        if (valueA > valueB) {
          comparison = 1;
        } else if (valueA < valueB) {
          comparison = -1;
        }
        return comparison;
      }

array.sort(compare);
```

But how can I add a header and divider at the right point when necessary?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: you can simply loop through and add the divider.

Comment: why you need then to be inside same array?

Comment: pseudocode would like `input.groupby(x=>x.group).orderby(x=>x.key).select(x=>x.prepend({header:x.key})).join({ divider: true })`

Comment: for the simple way, just loop through and add the divider *and header*. Do you encounter some specific problem?

Comment: use this to insert into index https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice (repost as english link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it with two `reduce()`s chained together.

```js
const input = [{
    name: 'Trevor Hansen',
    group: 'Group 1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Britta Holt',
    group: 'Group 2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane Smith ',
    group: 'Group 2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sandra Adams',
    group: 'Group 1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ali Connors',
    group: 'Group 1'
  },
  {
    name: 'John Smith',
    group: 'Group 2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sandra Williams',
    group: 'Group 2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tucker Smith',
    group: 'Group 1'
  },
]


const groupItems = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (typeof a[c.group] === "undefined") a[c.group] = []
    a[c.group] = [...a[c.group], c]
    return a
  }, {})
}

const step1 = groupItems(input)

console.log(step1)

const insertHeaders = (obj) => {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, vals], i, d) => {
    let r = [{
        header: key
      },
      ...vals,
    ]
    // this is needed to have the exact same array
    // that you presented as desirable output:
    // no divider at the last place
    if (i < d.length - 1) {
      r = [...r, {
        divider: true
      }]
    }
    a = [...a, ...r]
    return a
  }, [])
}

const step2 = insertHeaders(step1)
console.log(step2)
```

The benefit of this solution is that you don't need to know anything about the input, only that it has an `attribute` named `group`. Everything else is automatic:

- groups are created based on the `group` attribute
- items are placed after a header & before a divider (except the last group - that has no divider at the end)

---

But this brings out a question in me: why do you want to create an `array` like that? Using an array in this fashion is not the best idea in most cases. Groups are easily represented with an `object`, and there are functions to iterate over an `object` (`for...in`, `Object.entries`, etc.). If you need "headers" in the UI (e.g. table elements, etc.), it's better to move the header insertion in the displaying parts of the code (decouple from actual data) & only apply when you create the visuals. (Of course: not knowing much about your case, this solution can be totally sensible. :) )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really like the approach. I need this for displaying a list of users in a `<v-autocomplete>` dropdown menu in my `Vue.js` app using `Vuetify.js`. It works great now!

I could add the headers like you mentioned in the displaying parts of the code. However, in my case this is easier and can also be used better throughout my application.